# PyLint not finding class from Google Appengine SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pylint

We have a Python Application running on Google App Engine. For local development, we have the Google Appengine SDK installed. The setup is a little messed up as the application itself adds things to the sys.path. PyLint of course does not pick up those changes happening somewhere in some function.

I tried cleaning up the PyLint log by adding the Google Appengine SDK to the `PYTHONPATH`, which worked pretty good. Locally, I can now run PyLint for a specific set of folders and it reports a 10/10 with no errors (but a lot of `locally-disabled` statements). The same code is reporting exactly 1 issue on our CI system (We use Codeship). The message is `Module 'google.appengine.ext.ndb' has no 'JsonProperty' member (no-member)`.

The Googe Appengine SDK is installed inside the Codeship container and is added to the PYTHONPATH. Other functions/classes from the SDK get picked up correctly. The google.appengine.ext.ndb.**init**.py looks like this:

```
"""NDB -- A new datastore API for the Google App Engine Python runtime."""

__version__ = '1.0.10'

__all__ = []

from tasklets import *
__all__ += tasklets.__all__

from model import *  # This implies key.*
__all__ += model.__all__

from query import *
__all__ += query.__all__

from context import *
__all__ += context.__all__
```

The google.appengine.ext.ndb.model.py contains the `JsonProperty` class and has some magic as well:

```
# Update __all__ to contain all Property and Exception subclasses.
for _name, _object in globals().items():
  if ((_name.endswith('Property') and issubclass(_object, Property)) or
      (_name.endswith('Error') and issubclass(_object, Exception))):
    __all__.append(_name)
```

As I said, it works locally but does not on Codeship. Locally, `pylint --version prints

```
pylint 1.5.0,
astroid 1.4.5
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21)
[GCC 4.9.2]
```

while on Codeship, it says

```
pylint 1.5.0,
astroid 1.4.4
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2]
```

I am not sure what is going on here. There should be no major differences between Python 2.7.6 and 2.7.9, right? I have no idea how to further debug this either. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Working with a dev environment different than the CI environment is just asking for trouble. IMHO you'd get a better bang for your buck directing your efforts into making one env work for both instead of trying to fix the (endless, you'll see) flow of issues caused by the env deltas.

Comment: Well, the environment is pretty close, isn't it? I could try to get Python to the same version, but will this change anything related to my problem?

Comment: Not sure, one may have to check all the deltas between the version to be certain... Which is kinda my point - unknown/unbound amount of work ahead. If the versions would be the same this question wouldn't exist - zero work :)

Comment: Another thing to check is the GAE SDK version in the 2 envs - probably easier to get this one aligned, *maybe* it matters.

Comment: The GAE SDK is exactly the same. It gets installed by Ansible which is doing the exact same steps on dev and CI.The only real difference "should" be the Python version, and I guess this will be a PITA to update on Codeship.